# SQLAlchemy: Declarative Many to Many map for Parent with two primary keys

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to declare a many to many relationship using SQLAlchemy where my parent RowHeader can create Child Economists via a relationship table.   I keep running into errors around multiple join paths, lack of declared Foreign Keys.  I also have situations where the creation of children violates primary key constraints.   I only want a single Child but for it to be associated to many Parents.

```
# association table
row_econ_table = Table(
    "row_econ_table",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("rh_f_index", ForeignKey("row_header.f_index"), primary_key=True),  #left
    Column("rh_row", ForeignKey("row_header.row"), primary_key=True),   # left
    Column("econ_un_id", ForeignKey("economist.un_name_id"), primary_key=True),  #right
)

class RowHeader(Base):     # Parent (many with 2 pk)
    __tablename__ = "row_header"

    f_index: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    row: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    Names: Mapped[str] = mapped_column()
    Organization: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(nullable=True)
    economists: Mapped[List["Economist"]] = relationship(
        #cascade="all, delete",
        secondary=row_econ_table,
        foreign_keys=[f_index, row],
        primaryjoin="and_(RowHeader.f_index==row_econ_table.c.rh_f_index, " "RowHeader.row==row_econ_table.c.rh_row)",
        secondaryjoin="Economist.un_name_id==row_econ_table.c.econ_un_id"
    )
    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f"RowHeader(f_index={self.f_index!r}, row={self.row!r}, Names={self.Names!r}, Organization={self.Organization!r})"

class Economist(Base):    # Child (One on other side of assoc table)
    __tablename__ = "economist"

    un_name_id: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
```

My issue seems to be that I have two primary keys in my Parent which create multiple join paths.   I need two primary keys to make that table unique.

My goal is that:
Parent (RowHeader) creates all children (Economist) via relationship table.  If it doesn't exist, create it.  If it exists, just establish relationship to it via relationship table.  But, don't create multiples of the same child.

I'm not sure I can recount how many configurations I've tried!!

I've gotten the following errors:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for secondary join condition 'economist.un_name_id = row_econ_table.econ_un_id' on relationship RowHeader.economists.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation.


sqlalchemy.exc.NoForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship RowHeader.economists - there are no foreign keys linking these tables via secondary table 'row_econ_table'.  Ensure that referencing columns are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or specify 'primaryjoin' and 'secondaryjoin' expressions.
```

Also, I got this to create the tables once (lost track of what combination created this) but when the Parent tried to create a new Child that already exists, I got the primary key constraint error from the Child.

**Update**:  removing foreign_keys arg results in successful table creations.   So, progress!

But, when I try to add objects to the session which result in creating a row in the "economist" table that already exists, I get a Unique constraint error and rollback.

```
sqlite3.IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: economist.un_name_id
```

I guess I thought the session handled that for me but maybe it would if I didn't add_all and only added them only one at a time?   I'm using SQLLITE as my backend.   Not sure how to effect a merge or cause my "row_header" table to only be associated with an existing 'economist'

Now wondering if this is the key to my problem ...

[ORM Upsert Statements](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/orm/queryguide/dml.html#orm-queryguide-upsert)

[INSERT ... ON CONFLICT (SQLLITE)](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/sqlite.html#insert-on-conflict-upsert)

But, am unsure how to do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What ended up working was a few changes in the relationship table of the Parent (in my case RowHeader) adding joins.   Cascade depends on use case.

```
economists: Mapped[List["Economist"]] = relationship(
        cascade="save-update",
        secondary=row_econ_table,
        #foreign_keys=[f_index, row],
        primaryjoin="and_(RowHeader.f_index==row_econ_table.c.rh_f_index, " "RowHeader.row==row_econ_table.c.rh_row)",
        secondaryjoin="Economist.un_name_id==row_econ_table.c.econ_un_id"
    )
```

This cleared up the ambiguous joins.

On the IntegrityError, this was solved by looping through a session.merge() rather than session.add()

**Update**: I spoke too soon.  Merge creates an insert into col_header and a select from col_header but it does not populate associated tables.

```
2023-09-24 14:32:51,216 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine SELECT row_header.f_index AS row_header_f_index, row_header."row" AS row_header_row, row_header."Names" AS "row_header_Names", row_header."Organization" AS "row_header_Organization" 
FROM row_header 
WHERE row_header.f_index = ? AND row_header."row" = ?
2023-09-24 14:32:51,216 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00012s] ('w_1112.0', 2)
2023-09-24 14:32:51,231 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine INSERT INTO row_header (f_index, "row", "Names", "Organization") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
2023-09-24 14:32:51,231 INFO sqlalchemy.engine.Engine [generated in 0.00010s] ('w_1112.0', 2, 'Paul Ashworth', 'Capital Economics')
```